# Please help me to answer this conditional probability question

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

Question:

> [image]

So, for part (a), my answer is:

$$ {10 \choose 8} (0.6)^8 (0.4)^2 + {10 \choose 9}(0.6)^9 (0.4)^1 + {10 \choose 10 } (0.6)^10 (0.4)^0 = 0.1673$$

I am not sure how to answer part (b).

What I thought of:

Let $X$ = number of correct answers
    $Y$ = number of answers known

Therefore:

$P(X\ge 9|Y\ge 8) = \frac{P\left(X\ge9, Y=8 \right) + P\left(X\ge9, Y=9 \right) + P\left( X\ge 9 , Y=10 \right)}{P\left( Y\ge 8 \right)}$

In this case, the denominator is the answer to part (a).

I am not sure if I got the numerator right. I think I enumerated all the possible cases but now when I want to compute the first term in the numerator, I need to (I think) compute:

Probability know any 8 correct answers and guess any 1 answer correctly and any 1 answer wrong + Probability know any 8 correct answer and guess 2 correctly.

I am not sure how to compute the above and I am not even sure if this is the way to proceed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$P(X≥9, Y≥8) = P(X=9, Y=8) + P(X=10, Y=8) + P(X=9, Y=9) + P(X=10, Y=9) + P(X=10, Y=10)$$

---

How to calculate $P(X=9, Y=8)$?

- I knew 8 answers: the probability for that is $\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^8$
- I guessed one answer correct: the probability for that is $\frac{2}{5}\frac{1}{3}=\frac{2}{15}$
- I guessed one answer incorrect and didn't knew it: the probability
  for that is $1-\frac{3}{5}-\frac{2}{5}\frac{1}{3}=\frac{4}{15}$.

There are $\frac{10!}{8!\cdot 1!\cdot 1!}$ ways to order  these answers, so:

$$P(X=9, Y=8) = \frac{10!}{8!\cdot 1!\cdot 1!}\cdot \left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^8 \cdot \frac{2}{15} \cdot \frac{4}{15}$$

Comment: I don't understand the reason behind dividing $0.4$ by $3$ and $4$ I know $3$ and $4$ represent the number of choices available but why divide the probability of not knowing the answer by it? Also, is the sum $0.41079$? What are your thoughts on part (b)?

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread the question. I calculated P(X≥8), not P(Y≥8). The above hint is for part (b). Your answer for (a) is correct.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. In that case, for part (b), we are explicitly told to assume $C=3$. So, does this mean the answer is the first expression, without multiplying it by $0.3$?

Comment: No, then we compute P(X≥8). I shall do one for you, then you can hopefully do the others yourself.

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot. I just don't understand the 3rd bullet point, i.e. the probability of guess an incorrect answer. Why isn't this just $\frac{2}{3}$ i.e the complement of guessing an answer right?

Comment: Because you must be sure that you didn't knew the answer.

Comment: Okay, then for the case that we guess one answer correct, why don't we also require that we must not know the answer?

Comment: Your're right, sorry.  Can you now finish the question?

Comment: Based on your explanation and my understanding of it, is the answer $\frac{0.1135420416}{0.1673}=0.6787$?

Comment: Indeed, I get the same answer. You're welcome.

Comment: Do you think its possible to reduce the number of cases that need to be enumerated? I am wondering this because this question actually an exam question, and in my exam, there is time constraint and I am only allow the use of  a basic calculator.